For loop condition not working as per expectations
I am writing a code in this code I have to find the minimum steps which can take me from index 0 to index n-1. nums[i] represent the maximum jump I can take from ith index. (Reference leetcode Q45 jump II)
import java.util.*;
class HelloWorld {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] nums = {2,3,0,1,0};
        int val = jump(nums);
        System.out.println(val);
    }
    public static int jump(int[] nums) {
        int[] paths = new int[nums.length];
        int curr = nums.length-1;
        int dest = nums.length-1;
        for(int i=curr;i>=0 && nums[i]!=0;i--){
            int diff = dest-i;
            System.out.println("i=>"+i+" diff=>"+diff+" nums[i]=>"+nums[i]);

            // if(nums[i]==0){
            //     paths[i]=0;
            // }

            if(diff==0){
                paths[i]=0;
            }
            else if(diff<=nums[i]){
                paths[i]=1;
            }else{
                int min = diff;
                for(int j=1;j<=nums[i] && paths[i+j]!=0;j++){
                    // if(paths[i+j]!=0){
                        min=Math.min(1+paths[i+j],min);
                    // }
                    
                }
                paths[i]=min;
            }
            System.out.println(Arrays.toString(paths));
        }
        return paths[0];
    }

}

the code is working fine but when it comes to num[i]==0 the for loop breaks. whereas according to me it should skip the iteration.
If i use if statement instead of merging condition it runs well

&& nums[i]!=0  means "and the value is not zero" and the condition of the for needs to be true for it to continue - so if nums[i] is zero, the condition will result in false and the loop will stop ("loop breaks") -- you must change the condition to include nums[i] == 0 (not !=)

Whats your expected output for int[] nums = {2,3,0,1,0}; when passed to jump method?

but if condition is not met shouldn't it automatically skips and move to next iteration why break
expected output is {2,1,0,1,0}

you need to use "continue" to skip iteration

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

The for loop will stop executing when the loop condition is false. Since your loop condition is i>=0 && nums[i]!=0, it will stop either when i becomes negative OR nums[i] is equal to zero, whichever happens first. But you do not want to stop iterating when nums[i] is equal to zero, as there still could be more array elements to check; thus, this loop condition is logically incorrect.
Note that you can solve this problem in O(n) instead of O(n^2) by keeping track of the farthest location that can be reached in a single jump from the current segment. This also makes the code much shorter.
class Solution {
    public int jump(int[] nums) {
        int jumps = 0;
        for (int i = 0, maxReach = 0; maxReach < nums.length - 1; ++jumps) {
            int next = 0;
            for (; i <= maxReach; i++) next = Math.max(next, i + nums[i]);
            maxReach = next;
        }
        return jumps;
    }
}


oh yes now i realized it will stop if any condition is false.
thanks everyone

@jainyashit Happy to help. You should also note that you can solve the problem in linear time instead of quadratic time (which your current solution is), as shown in the code in my answer.
